# Novice C++ project using loops, if else and switch

Tags: c++

I have this project I am working on but I am currently stuck on being able to compare the prices of each package and how to implement it the instructions are as follows.

Project Requirements:

1. Develop a program that calculates the cost of a mobile device service. The cost of the service is determined by the base price and number of message units to be used. The packages are structured so that the basic package, package "A," is the least expensive if the user doesn't use many message units, however if the user uses more than the pre-paid minimum, the charge is significantly more for each additional message unit. Users who choose package "C" pay a flat rate for unlimited use. The cost of Package "B" is between these extremes. Details of the packages structure are listed here:
   Package Base Price  Additional Fees

A
$15.95
$.20 per message unit after 10 units.

B
$25.95
$.10 per message unit after 20 units.

C
$45.95
Unlimited message units.

2. This software is a "what if" price quote producer, so the user can continue to ask for quotes and see results until entering the letter "n" (not case sensitive)
3. The program will inform the user if it would be less expensive to change plans. (plan A to B or C etc) and display the cost saving.

Implementation Notes:
You should use both the switch and the if..else constructs in this program. The switch construct is good when you are checking a single variable against a number of different discrete values. A character variable (char) is discrete (you have one of a set of characters only) as are integer types (int). Strings and doubles are not discrete and will not work with the switch statement. if statements can be used anytime you have a relational operation such as equality, less than, etc. But you need to be careful when using a long series of if {...} else {...} constructs because of the confusion factor (Which if does this else go with? Where am I in this sequence of tests?).

The following code is what I have so far :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    int units;
    double priceA,priceB,priceC;
    char package, goAgain;

    do {
        cout << "Enter the Package chosen. Enter 'A' or 'a' for package A.\n";
        cout << "Enter 'b' or 'B' for package B.\n";
        cout << "Enter 'c' or 'C' for package C.\n";
        cin >> package;
        cout << "Enter the number of message units";
        cin >> units;
        if (units>10){
            priceA=15.95+(units-10)*.20;
            priceB=25.95+(units-20)*.20;
            priceC=45.95;
        }
        else if (units<=10){
            priceA=15.95;
            priceB=25.95;
            priceC=45.95;
        }
        if ((package='a') || (package='A')){
            cout <<"The cost of package A is" << " $" <<priceA << endl;

            if(priceA>priceB){
                cout << "By switching to package B you would save" << " $"
                     << priceA-priceB<<endl;
            }

        }

        cout<<"do you want to go again? y/n" << endl;
        cin >>goAgain;
    }
    while(goAgain=='y');
}
```

Comment: That's more text than I'm willing to read to figure out what your problem is.  Try reducing your problem to one thing, and ask a more focused and leaner question.  You'll get a better response that way.

Comment: Try using a debugger.  It's a lot faster than using StackOverflow as your debugging service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll work. Please cross-check output for different inputs for coz haven't had the time to do so.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    int units;
    double priceA,priceB,priceC;
    char package, goAgain;

    do {
        cout << "Enter the Package chosen. Enter 'A' or 'a' for package A.\n";
        cout << "Enter 'b' or 'B' for package B.\n";
        cout << "Enter 'c' or 'C' for package C.\n";
        cin >> package;
        cout << "Enter the number of message units";
        cin >> units;

        priceA=15.95;
        priceB=25.95;
        priceC=45.95;

        if (units>20){
            priceB += (units-20)*.10;
            priceA += (units-10)*.20;
        }
        else if (units>10){
            priceA += (units-10)*.20;
        }

        switch(package)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':   cout <<"\nThe cost of package A is" << " $" <<priceA << endl;
                        if(priceA>priceB)
                        {
                            cout << "\nBy switching to package B you would save" << " $" << priceA-priceB<<endl;
                        }
                        if(priceA>priceC)
                        {
                            cout << "\nBy switching to package C you would save" << " $" << priceA-priceC<<endl;
                        }
                        break;
            case 'b':  
            case 'B':   cout <<"\nThe cost of package B is" << " $" <<priceB << endl;
                        if(priceB>priceA)
                        {
                            cout << "\nBy switching to package A you would save" << " $" << priceB-priceA<<endl;
                        }
                        if(priceB>priceC)
                        {
                            cout << "\nBy switching to package C you would save" << " $" << priceB-priceC<<endl;
                        }
                        break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':   cout <<"The cost of package C is" << " $" <<priceC << endl;
                        if(priceC>priceB)
                        {
                            cout << "\nBy switching to package B you would save" << " $" << priceC-priceB<<endl;
                        }
                        if(priceC>priceA)
                        {
                            cout << "\nBy switching to package A you would save" << " $" << priceC-priceA<<endl;
                        }
                        break;
            default: cout << "\nIncorrect Input!!";
        }

        cout<<"do you want to go again? y/n" << endl;
        cin >>goAgain;
    }
    while(goAgain=='y');
}
```